# Git, repair file names and paths, encoding

Tags: git

I migrate hg-repository to git-repository.
And I have problems. Can You help me.

The problem with filenames (and paths) in git repository (in git extension).
The names are in Cyrillic (win 1251).
Can you suggest, how can I repair the git-repository?

The next screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Were they not encoded in this way before?

Comment: In hg-repository, they were in correct, in Cyrillic format.

Answer (score 1):

Git itself is largely<sup>1</sup> encoding-agnostic.  However, Git is *much* more *useful* if you stick with UTF-8 encoding, because that's the assumed default if you do not specify otherwise, and UTF-8 encoding avoids a number of pitfalls (though not all).  Most of the environment (tool-sets and the like) that work with the Git ecosystem prefer UTF-8 encoding.

If you do specify an encoding (by setting `LANG` to, e.g., `ru_RU.CP1251`), some tools will understand that the data are encoded in CP1251—but they will also think that your *terminal* is using CP1251, which may not be the case.  To work around this, you can use [luit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luit), as described in the answer to [How do I view cp1251 text file in UTF-8 console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178239/162084).

Mercurial's method of dealing with file name encoding is [described in the Mercurial Wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EncodingStrategy).  Converting to UTF-8 during a fast-export / fast-import conversion is possible, but a bit tricky.  It's also up to you whether you would like to convert file *content* (the export / import swap is the ideal time to do this, but obviously this requires careful detection of actual content encoding).

(You can also use `git filter-branch` after the fact to re-encode all file names while rebuilding the entire converted repository, but if you have not gotten very far, it's probably better to just redo the conversion from Hg to Git.)

---

<sup>1</sup>That is, Git tries not to interpret file names or file content itself, by simply storing snapshots.  But this breaks down in a lot of edge and corner cases.